# How to use regular expression to create columns with information from file name in python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm looking for smarter way to create two columns which will contain information from file name.

File names that I have to use looks like this:

"data - **05 A** - Tea 2017.xls"
"data - **05 B** - Tea 2017.xls"

But sometimes there is issue with file names and they look like this (additional - ):

"data - **07** - **C** - Tea 2017.xls"

The information that I want to add to dataframe is bolded. Is number and letter so my dataframe will look like this:

```
    X      Y       Z        Number    Letter
   0.32    0.23    0.234    05        A
   0.4     0.24    44       05        B
   23      21.2    0.4      07        C
```

Now I was just slicing the string like this:

```
for file_name in glob.glob(path):
        df = pd.read_html(file_name)[0]
        rows = df.shape[0]
        
         if "/A/" in path:
                        number = file_name[86:88]
                        letter = file_name[89:90]
                    
         elif "/B/" in path:
                        number = file_name[86:88]
                        letter = file_name[91:92]


          df["number"] = [number] * rows
          df["letter"] = [letter] * rows
```

Multiplicating this because I need this values to occur in whole dataset in this file from which I want to take this information about number and letter - tables that contains n number of rows

But I believe that smarter way it would be to use regex but I dont know how. I will really appreciate every help with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the examples you have given, the following regex works:

```
import re

file_names = [
    'data - 05 A - Tea 2017.xls', 
    'data - 07 - C - Tea 2017.xls', 
    'data - 05 B - Tea 2017.xls',
]

for file_name in file_names:
    number, letter = re.findall('data - ([0-9]+).*([A-Z]) - Tea.*', file_name)[0]
    print(number, letter)
```